# How can I disable scientific notation?

Tags: r, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a dataframe with a column of p-values, and I want to make a selection on these p-values.

```
> pvalues_anova
[1] 9.693919e-01 9.781728e-01 9.918415e-01 9.716883e-01 1.667183e-02
[6] 9.952762e-02 5.386854e-01 9.997699e-01 8.714044e-01 7.211856e-01
[11] 9.536330e-01 9.239667e-01 9.645590e-01 9.478572e-01 6.243775e-01
[16] 5.608563e-01 1.371190e-04 9.601970e-01 9.988648e-01 9.698365e-01
[21] 2.795891e-06 1.290176e-01 7.125751e-01 5.193604e-01 4.835312e-04
```

Selection way:

```
anovatest<- results[ - which(results$pvalues_anova < 0.8) ,]
```

The function works really fine if I use it in R. But if I run it in another application (galaxy), the numbers which don't have `e-01` e.g. `4.835312e-04` are not thrown out.

Is there another way to notate p-values, like `0.0004835312` instead of `4.835312e-04`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10)

Comment: That is a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 684):

You can effectively remove scientific notation in printing with this code:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Comment: If you want to revert it back as me :=), the default `scipen` is `0` (see `getOption("scipen")`)

Comment: Is there any possibility to use `scipen` only in one particular command, like in `print(x, dig = 6)`? Such as `summary(m1, scipen = 999)` or `print(x, scipen = 999)`? That would be cool. Because the global setting might be problematic.

Comment: @TMS: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509346/r-displays-numbers-in-scientific-notation: ``format(functionResult, scientific=FALSE);`` or ``as.integer(functionResult);``

Comment: @TMS how do you disable it by default so when a new session opens you don't have to redo the command?

Comment: The R default behavior that want to simplify your life makes it hell

Comment: @user4050 I reckon one could put the command in their .Rprofile. On linux (and maybe Mac?), one would make a file called .Rprofile in their home dir with that line in it. If you're one Windows, it looks like there's instructions here: http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: @HermanToothrot - this two minute video explains how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KazWu6i3NI0&list=PLcgz5kNZFCkzSyBG3H-rUaPHoBXgijHfC&index=91&t=0s

Comment: `withr` package has a handy function called `with_options` or `local_options` to revert back to default automatically

Answer (score 24):

```r
format(99999999,scientific = FALSE)
```

gives

```r
99999999
```

Comment: format(99999999,scientific = FALSE) will generate "99999999" (a character field, not numeric)

Comment: That's the correct and more general answer

Answer (score 21):

## Summarising all existing answers

###### (And adding a few of my points)

*Note : In the below explanation, `value` is the number to be represented in some (integer/float) format.*

### Solution 1 :

```
options(scipen=999)
```

### Solution 2 :

```
format(value, scientific=FALSE);
```

### Solution 3 :

```
as.integer(value);
```

### Solution 4 :

You can use integers which don't get printed in scientific notation. You can specify that your number is an integer by putting an "L" behind it

```
paste(100000L)
```

will print `100000`

### Solution 5 :

Control formatting tightly using 'sprintf()'

```
sprintf("%6d", 100000)
```

will print `100000`

### Solution 6 :

```
prettyNum(value, scientific = FALSE, digits = 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also find the `prettyNum(..., scientific = FALSE)` function useful for printing when I don't want trailing zeros. Note that these functions are useful for printing purposes, i.e., the output of these functions are strings, not numbers.

```
p_value <- c(2.45496e-5, 3e-17, 5.002e-5, 0.3, 123456789.123456789)
format(p_value, scientific = FALSE)
#> [1] "        0.00002454960000000" "        0.00000000000000003"
#> [3] "        0.00005002000000000" "        0.29999999999999999"
#> [5] "123456789.12345679104328156"


format(p_value, scientific = FALSE, drop0trailing = TRUE)
#> [1] "        0.0000245496"        "        0.00000000000000003"
#> [3] "        0.00005002"          "        0.29999999999999999"
#> [5] "123456789.12345679104328156"


# Please note that the last number's last two digits are rounded:
prettyNum(p_value, scientific = FALSE, digits = 16)
#> [1] "0.0000245496"        "0.00000000000000003" "0.00005002"
#> [4] "0.3"                 "123456789.1234568"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers, if, for example, one would like to use the previously mentioned `format()` with dplyr on the whole column, then `format()` needs to be wrapped inside the lambda function:

```
colors <- c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange")
floats <- runif(5) / 1000000

df <- data.frame(colors, floats) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

[@yuskam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372752/yuskam) put this in a comment (i.e. use `withr`) further up. If you're developing a function/package this is helpful. I am answering here to increase the profile of that suggestion.

```r
# show standard setting to confirm ground truth
getOption("scipen")

vect <- c(4.835312e-06, 4.835312e-05, 4.835312e-04)
print(vect)

print_non_scientific <- function(x) {
  # show setting within function
  withr::local_options(list(scipen = 999))
  print(getOption("scipen"))
  print(x)
}

print_non_scientific(vect)

# show standard setting to confirm that the function did not change it
getOption("scipen")
```

Output on my machine:

```r
> # show standard setting to confirm ground truth
> getOption("scipen")
[1] 0
> 
> vect <- c(4.835312e-06, 4.835312e-05, 4.835312e-04)
> print(vect)
[1] 4.835312e-06 4.835312e-05 4.835312e-04
> 
> print_non_scientific <- function(x) {
+   # show setting within function
+   withr::local_options(list(scipen = 999))
+   print(getOption("scipen"))
+   print(x)
+ }
> 
> print_non_scientific(vect)
[1] 999
[1] 0.000004835312 0.000048353120 0.000483531200
> 
> # show standard setting to confirm that the function did not change it
> getOption("scipen")
[1] 0
```