# Disable scientific notation when converting to JSON

Tags: json, r

I am having trouble with converting a data structure to JSON without representing numerics in scientific notation.

```
library(rjson)

options(scipen=1000)

toJSON(c(1200000000, 400000))

# [1] "[1.2e+08,400000]"
```

How can I make it output `"[1200000000,400000]"` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Are you using an old version of R or rjson?

Comment: on R 2.15.0 and rjson 0.2.8 my output matches WYi's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable scientific notation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

**Update from 2018:** use `jsonlite` like everyone nowadays:

```
> toJSON(c(1200000000, 400000))
[1200000000,400000]
```

---

**Original answer from 2012:**

I would also suggest to transform the numbers to strings before passing to `toJSON` just as @gauden wrote above. But if you would not do that try `RJSONIO` package (which is faster anyway) which has a `digits` option:

```
>  toJSON(c(1200000000, 400000), digits = 10)
[1] "[  1200000000,      400000 ]"
```

But this would result in some extra whitespace as you can see.

---

**Update:** it seems that @gauden deleted his answer so adding some details

You might call e.g. `format` before transforming the "numbers" to JSON like:

```
> toJSON(format(c(1200000000, 400000), scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE))
[1] "[\"1200000000\",\"400000\"]"
```

Comment: Thanks @daroczig. But I have a much larger object to convert to JSON, so manually formatting each numeric isn't scalable in my case.

Comment: You can still use `RJSONIO::toJSON` with `digits` parameter, but I am really not sure why is it a bad idea to run `format` (which is vectorized) on a large object. E.g.: `format(mtcars, decimal.mark=',')`

Comment: RJSONIO still output scientific notation. Format converts numbers to strings, not ideal.

Comment: @daroczig it does not work when you do this: toJSON(c(0.00007757))

Comment: @Jfly if you need more significant digits, set the related argument of `toJSON`

Comment: @daroczig You can try jsonlite::toJSON(c(0.00007757), digits = 20). It shows scientific notation. But it turns out jsonlite::toJSON(c(0.00007757), digits = 6) works.