# R displays numbers in scientific notation

Tags: r

The result of function was displayed in scientific notation, I want to change it back to normal, but only for that function, I don't want to change the global setting. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do:

```
format(functionResult, scientific=FALSE);
```

or:

```
as.integer(functionResult);
```

Comment: You could use round to specify a number decimals as well:

```round(functionResult,2)```