# Control the number of decimals in scientific notation

Tags: r, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a vector:

```
c(0, 1.23, 0.0000123)
```

and I would like to get scientific notation defining the number of decimals. Something like:

```
# [1] 0.000e+00 1.230e+00 1.230e-05
```

or like:

```
# [1] 0.000000e+00 1.230000e+00 1.230000e-05
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [First hit on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509346/r-displays-numbers-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: I have tried google but I cannot find the answer

Comment: The result is `[1] "0.00e+00" "1.23e+00" "1.23e-05"`. It is two decimals, I need 3 or 6

Comment: Let `x <- c(0, 1.23, 0.0000123)`. Then try `sprintf("%.3e", x)`. And you should get `[1] "0.000e+00" "1.230e+00" "1.230e-05"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

Let

```
x <- c(0, 1.23, 0.0000123)
```

and try

```
sprintf("%.3e", x)
[1] "0.000e+00" "1.230e+00" "1.230e-05"
```

If you don't want the quotes and the `[1]` to be displayed then do this

```
cat(sprintf("%.3e", x),"\n")
0.000e+00 1.230e+00 1.230e-05
```

Comment: It works. Thank you