# how to remove scientific notation for plot()

Tags: r

I have a plot

[image]

How can I format the x and y axis so they are not in scienftic notation?

Thank you.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can do this by adjusting the scientific notation setting for R in general. This should pretty much disable it:
`options(scipen=999)`

Comment: That worked! Do you know how to format the x axis with commas? so 50000 is 50,000

Comment: You can do that to individual numbers like this: `format(1e6, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)`
But to get the axis like that you will have to manually replace the entire axis, which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to replace the axis to get the format with the commas?

Comment: As I said, it is a bit painful and involved. I would need to know more about your specific case to give an exact solution. In general you disable the axis with the `xaxt='n'` parameter in the plot function, then manually add an axis in with the "axis" function. Read `help(axis)` for full explanation or just post another question with more details about your situation.