# Overriding scientific notation in ggplot's legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend-properties

This should be very simple, but I can't seem to find a solution. I am looking for the equivalent of scale_y_continuous, or scale_x_continuous in ggplot, but for the legend rather than the chart axes.

Very simply, I am getting 5e+05 where I want 500000.

I assume this can be controlled through something like legend.text inside theme:

```
legend.text=element_text(scale_continuous)
```

Can someone please provide the correct code? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the correct reproducible example?

Comment: In lieu of a reproducible example, have you tried adjusting the scientific notation option in r? E.g. `options(scipen=999)` - See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r