# Remove all leading zeros and turn number into a positive

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert .000278 into 278 in R but all functions I see can only move it to .278. It needs to be a whole, positive number.

Is there a function that will remove the .0+ preceding a number??

Comment: `.000278*1000000`? Is the number a character or numeric?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to apply this to many numbers at once (otherwise I might not understand the question).

```
a <- c(0.003, 0.0056, 0.000278)#Example data
a*(10^(nchar(a)-2))
[1]   3  56 278
```

Make sure scientific notation is disabled with `scipen`, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r) post (e.g., by doing `options(scipen=999)`. This is important because `nchar` counts the number of characters the numbers have (minus 2 for "0.").

Another approach. Use the package `stringr`.

```
a <- c(0.003, 0.0056, 0.000278)#Example data
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_replace(a, "0.", ""))
[1]   3  56 278
```

Note that with this method you need to convert the output of `str_replace` back to numeric using `as.numeric` (not ideal).

Comment: I think `a*(10^(nchar(a)-2))` is the best approach.  You always want to avoid unnecessary coercion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed the order.

Comment: @RichardScriven `nchar` approach fails for `a <- c(0.00003, 0.0056, 0.0000278)`

Comment: You have to make sure that scientific notation is disabled. Try doing this first: options(scipen=999).

Answer (score 2):

Or use

`substr` and `regexpr` what gives exactly what you wanted

```
x <- 0.000278
as.numeric(substr(x ,regexpr("[^0.]",x),nchar(x)))
[1] 278
```

And this also works for different numbers, just set:

`options("scipen"=100, "digits"=10) # Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e-8)`

and you could try for example:

```
z <- 0.000000588
as.numeric(substr(z ,regexpr("[^0.]",z),nchar(z)))
[1] 588
```

Comment: @Richard Scriven good point, unfortunately I've made a mistake which I corrected (see my edit in a post).

Comment: Your solution heavily relies on `options("scipen"=100, "digits"=10)`. One should change R default options to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (`len` is adjustable):

```
a <- 0.000278
a*(10^match(T,round(a, 1:(len=10)) == a)) # counts the number of decimals places
# 278
```

Use `as.numeric(a)` in case `a` is of type character.

Answer (score 0):

```
>  as.numeric(gsub("^[0.]*", "", paste(0.000278)))
[1] 278
```