# probability / likelihood per observation between 0 and 1 svm r

Tags: r, svm, probability

I,ve a question regarding the output format of probabilities for each observation.

```
Current output:
                0            1
2282 9.791608e-01 2.083920e-02 
135  4.769759e-01 5.230241e-01 
2036 9.807866e-01 1.921336e-02

Desired output:                      just like the example below produces
           1         0
9  0.4268682 0.5731318
10 0.4268682 0.5731318
4  0.4268682 0.5731318
7  0.2590067 0.7409933
2  0.2590067 0.7409933
```

With the reproducible example below, I get the desired output as probabilities between 0 and 1. Though, when I run the exact same code with another bigger data set I want to run my analysis on, containing 1100 variables and 10000 observations where each cell is filled with either a 0 or a 1, so same data set bigger size, then I get the current output as shown above.

```
# data preparation
A <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) 
B <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1) 
C <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
train <- data.frame(A, B, C) 
train[] <- lapply(train, as.factor)


# randomize data
train <- train[sample(nrow(train)),]


# create 10 equal folds
number_folds <- 2
folds <- cut(seq (1, nrow(train)), breaks = number_folds, labels = FALSE)


# Vectors created to store the initialized values with 0’s
accuracy_SVM <- rep(0,number_folds)


# install packages required for SVM and NB
install.packages("e1071")
library("e1071")


# Cross validation, data segmentations and running the model
for(i in 1:number_folds){
  testIndexes <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  testData <- train[testIndexes ,]
  trainData <- train[-testIndexes ,]

SVM_model <- svm(A ~ ., data = trainData, probability = T)
classification_svm <- predict(SVM_model, testData, type ="response", probability = T)
accuracy_SVM[i] <- sum(classification_svm == testData$A) / nrow (testData)
}

attr(classification_svm, "probabilities")
```

Sorry that I cannot provide my own data set to help you reproducing the same output, but I couldn't formulate the question any clearer. Help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: So is the question how to disable scientific notation in the printed output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r

Comment: @user20650 haven't thought of that but you were right. Thanks a lot!