# Prevent number formatting when using tidy

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using tidy to format the Chunks of my rMarkdown file. How can I prevent that numbers, especially long numberes, are formatted by tidy?  For example:

```
set.seed(3585)
n=10000 
loginkomens_prog1 = c(rep(10,0.3*n), rnorm(0.7*n, mean=11, sd=1))
inkomens_prog1 = exp(loginkomens_prog1) 
inkomens_prog1[inkomens_prog1>100000]=100000
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
hist(inkomens_prog1,main="Programma1",xlim=c(0,200000))
```

Tidy reformat it, like this:

```
set.seed(3585)  
n = 10000 
loginkomens_prog1 = c(rep(10, 0.3 * n), rnorm(0.7 * n, mean = 11, 
    sd = 1))  
inkomens_prog1 = exp(loginkomens_prog1)  
inkomens_prog1[inkomens_prog1 > 1e+05] = 1e+05  
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))  
hist(inkomens_prog1, main = "Programma1", xlim = c(0, 2e+05))
```

I would prefer that it stays 100000 instead of 1e+05. Is it possible? Or is it better that I set `tidy=FALSE` for that chunk (and that I format it manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidy_source` from the `formatR` package is used to tidy up the contents, and what it does, ultimately, is to `cat()` the output.

So, to prevent your number from getting converted to scientific notation, you have to set the `scipen` option appropriately (see e.g. [How to disable scientific notation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r)).

Example:

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".R")
cat("inkomens_prog1[inkomens_prog1>100000]=100000", file = temp)

formatR::tidy_source(temp)
# inkomens_prog1[inkomens_prog1 > 1e+05] = 1e+05

options(scipen = 99)
formatR::tidy_source(temp)
# inkomens_prog1[inkomens_prog1 > 100000] = 100000
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought about scientific notation! To make things look cleaner, I added `tidy.opts=options(scipen = 99)` to my R chunk.