# Same Excel data, same .RMD file, different markdown result

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Problem: Same code, same data but different output.
I recently hired a someone and set him up on R. When we try to knit a .pdf file using the same .rmd file with the same data we get different results. In short, the code reads an Excel file and writes out a value from one of the cells. From my PC, the output is "100,000". From his PC, it appears as "1e+05". The question is how do I make the output "100,000" from both computers? As you look at the code you will see that I'm printing a vector using the code

```
av$PreTaxValue <- prettyNum(round(av$PreTaxValue, 0), big.mark = ",")
```

It's odd to me that one number in the vector is in scientific notation, and the other values have a comma.

I placed the markdown (.rmd) file, the Excel data, and the two (one from each computer) .PDF output files into a [Github repo](https://github.com/rexmacey/debug). When knitted the .rmd creates a .pdf. The Control.xlsx workbook has the data. debug1.pdf has the output the way I think it should be. The Taxable row, PreTaxvValue column has "100,000". In debug.pdf, this value appears as "1e05"

### Any help appreciated.  Additional details: we both installed tinytex. Below is information on the versions we are using.

```
R.Version() from my PC produces:    
$platform   
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"    
$arch   
[1] "x86_64"    
$os    
[1] "mingw32"    
$system    
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"    
$status    
[1] ""    
$major    
[1] "3"    
$minor    
[1] "5.1"    
$year    
[1] "2018"    
$month    
[1] "07"    
$day    
[1] "02"    
$svn rev    
[1] "74947"    
$language    
[1] "R"    
$version.string    
[1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"    
$nickname    
[1] "Feather Spray"

From my colleague's PC: R.Version() produces:    
$platform    
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"    
$arch    
[1] "x86_64"    
$os    
[1] "mingw32"    
$system    
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"    
$status    
[1] ""    
$major    
[1] "3"    
$minor    
[1] "5.1"    
$year    
[1] "2018"    
$month    
[1] "07"    
$day    
[1] "02"    
$svn rev    
[1] "74947"    
$language    
[1] "R"    
$version.string    
[1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"    
$nickname    
[1] "Feather Spray"
```

Comment: to disable scientific notation try `options(scipen=100)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation

Answer (score 1):

As [Alaleh A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5091507/alaleh-a) mentioned in a comment, you can essentially disable scientific notation by changing the global `scipen` option:

```
options(scipen=100)
```

as discussed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation). However, if you don't want that as a global setting, you can change

```
prettyNum(round(av$PreTaxValue, 0), big.mark = ",")
```

to

```
prettyNum(format(round(av$PreTaxValue, 0), scientific = FALSE), big.mark = ",")
```

(and similarly for `av$AfterTaxValue`). Consider the following:

```r
x = 100000.00
prettyNum(round(x, 0), big.mark = ",")
#> [1] "1e+05"
prettyNum(format(round(x, 0), scientific = FALSE), big.mark = ",")
#> [1] "100,000"
```