# R changed .dta variable to numeric with range

Tags: r

I have wide format data in a .dta file, merged by 'ID' that's numeric. When I look at the preview on R, the data are fine. However, when I read it into R and open it using View(), all the numeric variables in the data frame have been changed to '8.00000e+01', '6.039095e+09' etc.

I've never encountered this problem while importing datasets before. Can someone explain how to change it back and why this is happening?

Comment: On the basis of what you've told us so far, no we can't.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  How are you reading the file into R?  Are the "numeric" variables now of character type or is it simply that their display format has changed?

Comment: Run `options(scipen = 999)` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate here: [How to disable scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation)

In a nutshell: if you want to change only one column, just change scipen to 999, change value to character type, and revert back.

PS. I assume that you don't have to do calculation at the ID column since it is unique.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 10000000000, y = 200000000)
df
      x     y
1 1e+10 2e+08

options(scipen = 999)
df
            x         y
1 10000000000 200000000
df$x <- as.character(df$x)

options(scipen = 0)
df
            x     y
1 10000000000 2e+08
```