# Is there an R function to adjust scale in the axis for a barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe called crashes_deaths_injuries_TA_pop that looks like:

| TA_name | Population |
| --- | --- |
| Gore | 34466 |
| Buller | 444444 |
| Cluth | 34455 |

I am trying to show the data with a bar chart however, the scale of x-axis is messed up and I'm not sure how to . I know this must be easy but I am new to coding so I am struggling.

here is my code for the bar chart:

```
ggplot(crashes_deaths_injuries_TA_pop, aes(x = reorder(TA_name, Population), y = Population, fill = Population)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", direction = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Population", fill = "Population",
       title = "Populations of South Island TA's | 2018",
       caption = "Data: Census 2018, StatsNZ") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I was also wondering how can you add like the population as a number at the end of each bar for each TA_name

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Is it the scale or the scientific notation that is "messed up"? (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation/5352328#5352328)

Comment: I have removed the scientific notation but now I want to edit the breaks, would this be with breaks command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = )` to edit ticks of x axis of yours and use `geom_text` to add `Population` next to the bar chart. Here's an example.

```
ggplot(crashes_deaths_injuries_TA_pop, aes(x = reorder(TA_name, Population), y = Population, fill = Population)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", direction = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Population", fill = "Population",
       title = "Populations of South Island TA's | 2018",
       caption = "Data: Census 2018, StatsNZ") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5e05, 0.5e05)) + geom_text(aes(label = Population, y = Population+0.18e05))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the "0, 5e05, 0.5e05" of  scale_y_continuous and "+0.18e05" for geom_text just for future use, not really sure

Comment: @scumbagsurfer First, `breaks = seq(0, 5e05, 0.5e05)` makes ticks of x-axis. As you can see, ticks are sequencs of `50000 = 0.5e05, 1e05, 1.5e05, ...`. You can change space between ticks by changing `0.5e05`. Second, `+0.18e05` is added to move location of text that to make numbers not overlapped with bars. I manually tested several numbers and find appropriate number for you.