# My R bar plot is not showing the difference in yearly sales clearly

Tags: r, data-visualization

After successfully running my bar plot, I have a **PROBLEM** where the numbers on the y axis are in codes and not in full, and instead of showing normal figures, it shows codes like 0e+00.

I would like the Y axis to show between 102,000 and 106,000.

The bar plot also has different figures. But it is not showing clearly the difference in yearly sales.

```
# Table of average total sales by year
yearly_sales <- DataSet %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(sales = mean(Weekly_Sales))
summarise(yearly_sales)
mycols <- c("#FF7F50", "#DE3163", "#6495ED")

# Bar chart for Average Yearly Sales 2010 to 2012
barplot(height = yearly_sales$sales, names = yearly_sales$Year, col = mycols)
```

[image: This is the table I am trying to visualize]

The bar plot is shown here.
[image]

How can I get the chart to show clearly the difference in sales and how can I get the actual values too instead of 0e+00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `ylim` and `xpd`, though I caution representing your data this way as it exaggerates the true difference between years and is a general violation of data visualization. The figure you represented in your question is more accurate.

At any rate, if you wanted to do this:

```
# Example data
data <- c(1033660, 1046239, 1059670)

# Plot, `a` saves the position of the x axis to place years text
a <- barplot(data, ylim = c(1020000, 1060000), xpd = FALSE, col = c("#FF7F50", "#DE3163", "#6495ED"))
axis(1, at = a, labels = c(2010, 2011, 2012), tick = FALSE)
```

`ylim` sets the limits and `xpd` clips the overhang at the lower axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either temporally [disabling scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352328/6574038) ,

```
op <- options(scipen=999)  ## set par
barplot(sales ~ Year, Yearly_sales, col=2:4)
par(op)  ## restore old par
```

or `formatC`ing.

```
barplot(sales ~ Year, data=Yearly_sales, col=2:4, yaxt='n')
axis(side=2, at=axTicks(2), labels=formatC(axTicks(2), format='fg'))
```

Just like [*@jpsmith*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72106933/6574038) I'm neither a fan of narrowing the x-axis, because that's exactly how folks pimp their statistics and give the impression of huge differences while they are actually tiny, thus deceiving their readers. **Please don't do this**.

It might be more professional to show the percentage differences, e.g. compared to the first measurement in 2010.

```
Yearly_sales <- transform(Yearly_sales, 
                          diff=(sales - sales[Year == 2010])/sales[Year == 2010])

barplot(diff ~ Year, Yearly_sales, col=2:4, yaxt='n', ylim=c(-.04, 0))
axis(side=2, at=axTicks(2), labels=paste0(axTicks(2)*100, '%'))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
Yearly_sales <- structure(list(sales = c(1033660, 1046239, 1059670), Year = 2012:2010, 
    diff = c(-0.0245453773344532, -0.0126747006143422, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```