# R: Disabling Scientific Notation In ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

**I am trying to disable scientific notation from all plots produced using the ggplot library.**

Normally, I use the following command to disable scientific notation :

```
options(scipen=999)
```

However, this above code does not seem to disable the scientific notation for plots such as the one below (e.g. in the legend):

```
g1 = ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = st_trans,
            aes(fill = cut_number(min_distance, 9)),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu",
                      name = "Minimum Distance") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Minimum Distance",
         subtitle = "Source: Your Data",
         caption = "Your Caption") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

**Does anyone know if there is some "master command" that can disable the scientific notation in all plots produced using ggplot?**

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting; if you set `options(scipen = 999999)` do you still get the scientific notation in the legend?

Comment: @ jared_mamrot: thank you for your reply! I tried your code and unfortunately the scientific notation in the legend does not change :(

Comment: I usually set it to 999999 and don't have that issue; I'll look into it and get back to you

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-can-i-disable-scientific-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of digging it looks like the issue is with `cut_number()`, rather than with ggplot. The `cut_number()` function is a wrapper for base::cut.default and it has a 'default' scientific notation (i.e. it ignores whatever scipen you set). Luckily `cut_number()` accepts a "dig.lab" argument so you can change it to suit.

E.g. setting dig.lab to 50 (the max) should fix the issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)

options(scipen = 999)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 100000, 10000),
                 y = seq(5, 500000, 50000))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = cut_number(y, 4))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = cut_number(y, 4, dig.lab = 50))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ jared_mamrot: thank you so much for your answer! this works! just a question - for the dig.lab argument, is there some golden rule to remember? for example, if the biggest number I have is 999999 ... should I set dig.lab = 50? thank you so much!

Comment: If the biggest number you have is 999999 (6 digits) you can use `dig.lab = 7` and you'll get 'normal' notation. I tried "dig.lab = 100" and the function said "the max is 50", so I'm just going to use "50" in my own scripts in future, but if you want anything over N digits to be scientific notation, use "dig.lab = N". Does that make sense?