# Do not want scientific notation on plot axis again

Tags: plot, axis, notation

When I draw the ROC curve with the following code, the x-axis values are still in scientific notation form, e.g. 0.2 behaves as 2e-01：
options(scipen = 1)
options(digits = 1)
plot(rocmodelTDF,print.auc=TRUE,print.thres=TRUE,main="ROC  CURVE",legacy.axes=TRUE,col="#CC6666",print.thres.col="#CC6666",identity.col="black",identity.lty=1,identity.lwd=1)

No matter what I do to change the options parameter, I can't solve the problem. I want my x-axis to be in decimal places

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-can-i-disable-scientific-notation)