How can I remove the letter "e" from my integer data in Rstudio matrix?
I used read.csv to import a data file into Rstudio. When I open the CSV in notepad, it is fully numeric with no "e" in the data (confirmed by using control F). However, when I open the csv in R some of the zeroes have "E" as part of scientific notation. This means I cant do anything with the data, I keep getting errors that there are characters in it, such as the following:
Error in aldex.clr.function(as.data.frame(reads), conds, mc.samples, denom,  : 
not all reads are integers
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addCluster': invalid subscript 'e' in 'altExp(<TreeSummarizedExperiment>, type="character", ...) 

I have tried making a new CSV and making sure there is no scientific notation in Excel. Ive tried converting the data into a matrix, then the matrix into a numeric matrix. Ive tried using replace commands wihtin R. I dont understand why only some of the 0s have these e's, and I dont understand why they are there when the actual CSV itself has no e's in the data at all. I am totally at a loss for why this problem is occurring and how to fix it.
Here is my code:
# Load files
counts  <- read.csv("C:/Users/willw/IS Data/ISdataobservationsnew.csv", row.names = 1)   # Abundance table (e.g. ASV data; to assay data)
tax     <- read.csv("C:/Users/willw/IS Data/ISdatataxonomy.csv", row.names = 1)     # Taxonomy table (to rowData)
samples <- read.csv("C:/Users/willw/IS Data/ISdatameta.csv", row.names = 1)  # Sample data (to colData)

library(mia)
counts <- as.matrix(counts)

mode(new) = "numeric"

tse<- TreeSummarizedExperiment(
  assays =  SimpleList(counts = counts),
  colData = DataFrame(samples),
  rowData = DataFrame(tax))

tse

taxonomyRanks(tse)

checkTaxonomy(tse)

dput(counts[7670:7700])



# Agglomerate by genus and subset by prevalence
tse <- subsetByPrevalent(tse, rank = "Genus", prevalence = 10/100)

# Transform count assay to relative abundances
tse <- transformAssay(tse, assay.type = "counts", method = "relabundance")
# Load package


library(ALDEx2)

set.seed(123)
x <- aldex.clr(assay(tse), tse$bd.status)

dput()

tse <- addAlpha(
  tse, assay.type = "counts", index = "observed", name = "observed",
  detection = 1)

library(scater)
plotColData(
  tse,
  "observed",
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Sample types", y = expression(Richness[Observed]))
library(vegan)

set.seed(174923)
altExp(tse, "prevalent") <- addCluster(
  altExp(tse, "prevalent"),
  assay.type = "counts",
  by = "cols",
  HclustParam(method = "ward.D2", dist.fun = getDissimilarity, metric = "bray"),
  full = TRUE,
  clust.col = "hclust")

the dput of my table (subset of rows that I think are causing the problem):
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 6.44e-05, 0, 0, 0, 3.22e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.44e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 6.44e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.22e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0.000160994, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(6L, 15L), dimnames = list(c("OTU_7670", 
                                                                   "OTU_7671", "OTU_7672", "OTU_7673", "OTU_7674", "OTU_7675"), 
                                                                 c("Y22116", "Y22119", "Y22310", "Y22311", "Y23304", "Y22226", 
                                                                   "Y20EB05", "N22497", "N22118", "N22306", "N22RR05", "N22399", 
                                                                   "N22317", "N22319", "N23RR04")))


Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-can-i-disable-scientific-notation
There are several ways to fix it. (Refer to Deepthi Tabitha Bennet's summary)

These values are not character and I seriously doubt they are interpreted as such. It rather looks like your counts, which should be integer, are double values. But your code is long and complex and you don’t even specify where the error occurs or which object the dput output shows.

As @Roland said, you need to simplify and clarify your code to show us something that generates the error.  The data you showed would not.

@Will W the e is a scientific notation for a power of ten: 6.44e-5= 6.44 * 10^(-5) = 0,0000644. It simply means that your numbers are closer to 0 in this case. There is no e. It just stands for the number. Just use options(scipen=999) to mitigate this problem.
